# Concurrent method works much longer than simple method. Why?

Tags: java, concurrency

I wrote simple method for reading one file and writing into 2 files. Also I wrote this method with 3 threads, where the first thread reads line-by-line file, the second and the third write readed line into own file. My parallel version of method works in 30 times longer than simple sequential method. Please, help to understand what I do wrong, and how I should do this method to not shooting in my leg)))

```
private static class Tee {
        private BufferedReader reader;
        private PrintWriter fWriter;
        private PrintWriter sWriter;
        volatile boolean done;
        String buffer;
        volatile int readCount;
        volatile int firstWriteCount;
        volatile int secondWriteCount;

        public Tee(BufferedReader reader, PrintWriter fWriter, PrintWriter sWriter) {
            this.reader = reader;
            this.fWriter = fWriter;
            this.sWriter = sWriter;
        }

        public void teeWhileInsideCo() throws InterruptedException {
            Thread reader = new Thread(new LineReader());
            Thread fWriter = new Thread(new LineWriter(this.fWriter, 0));
            Thread sWriter = new Thread(new LineWriter(this.sWriter, 1));

            reader.start();
            fWriter.start();
            sWriter.start();

            reader.join();
            fWriter.join();
            sWriter.join();
        }

        private class LineReader implements Runnable {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                String line;
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        line = reader.readLine();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        line = null;
                    }

                    while (readCount != firstWriteCount || readCount != secondWriteCount) {
                    }

                    if (line == null) {
                        done = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    buffer = line;
                    readCount++;
                }
            }
        }

        private class LineWriter implements Runnable {
            private PrintWriter writer;
            private int number;

            public LineWriter(PrintWriter writer, int n) {
                System.out.println(Tee.this);
                this.writer = writer;
                this.number = n;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    while (!done && ((number == 0 ? firstWriteCount : secondWriteCount) == readCount)) {
                    }
                    if (done) {
                        break;
                    }

                    writer.println(buffer);
                    if (number == 0) {
                        firstWriteCount++;
                    } else {
                        secondWriteCount++;
                    }
                }
                writer.flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: First, maybe you could explain why you think that using threads would be a help. You clearly intended that your three threads should operate in lock-step with each other, which means that even if you fix the problems in this code, it will never be any faster than a single-threaded program that does the same thing.

Comment: It's not just slower in parallel, it's also incorrect (e.g. because you can't increment an int atomically, even when it is volatile).

Comment: Ok, I understand, that some operations need additional time. You said that there are problems in this code. Can you show me them?

Comment: The _first_ problem is that it performs a task for which multi-threading adds no value. If all you want to do is write a `tee` program, then the best way to do it is with a single thread. The whole point of using threads is to allow two or more activities in your program to proceed concurrently with one another and _independently_ of each other. In your example, the activities depend on each other _at every step._ When that is the case, there is simply no reason to do those steps in different threads.

Comment: Your idea to write in two files parallelized is not wrong. The problem is that you haven't really applied proper synchronization or mechanisms that make it *run* parallelized. I suggest you to start with an easier exersice: Write a program that writes into two files parallelized. Or write a program that reads a file and writes in another one parallelized. Then start extending those programs. The most difficult part is to exchange data between reader and writer properly. Do that last.

Comment: If you want to improve the performance, you should consider that a) you don’t need to do it in terms of *lines*. Lines are irrelevant to this operation, but since you are requesting them, the code has to search the characters for line breaks, then construct string objects to represent these lines, which implies copying the character data. But further b) there’s not even a reason to process *characters*. You are decoding the byte stream to characters, to encode the characters to bytes again *two times*. Just read from an `InputStream` into a buffer and write this buffer to two `OutputStream`s.